# C++ converting NULL and NON-NULL values to pointer

Tags: c++

I am trying to call a function which accepts only pointers of the type
`void put_func(T *obj)`. My requirement is to have this function take `true/false` and return `true/false` when I use `get_func()`. Since it is a pointer I am not able to pass those values. Are there any ways to achieve this?

EDIT:
My basic question is how to pass `true` or `false` when the function takes a generic pointer.

EDIT 2: Modified the question to make it clear.

Comment: What is "NOT-NULL"? You seem to be pretending that a pointer value is a boolean variable. Why?

Comment: Totally unclear to me. Why are you passing `void*`? There is no way to answer this without understanding what `put_func` does with the value you're giving it.

Comment: Sounds like an xy problem.  What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I need a way to differentiate `true` or `false` that I pass to that function. put_func simulates a hash table. I need to store `false` initially and then change them to `true`, when a certain condition is achieved.

Comment: @user2761431 Then why does the function accept `T*` instead of `bool`?

Comment: @all My basic question how do you simulate `true` or `false` when the function takes only a pointer.

Comment: @Rotem It is a generic function, it can take any value.

Comment: @user2761431 I see now, your edit is much clearer to me.

Comment: Just pass a null pointer, as you are doing, then for the 'true' case pass a pointer to the actual kind of function you assert in the prototype. Don't get involved with a third kind of pointer that will only confuse those who come after you.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using your trying to use your `T*` hash-table emulator to store a collection of `bool`.

You cannot take a reference to the literal `true` or `false`. You'll need to manage the lifetime of a `bool` variable instead.

```
template<typename T>
void put_func(T *obj) {}

int main(){
    bool myBool = true;
    put_func(&myBool);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Casting `0` (the integer constant) to `T*` is safe, and gives you a `nullptr`, but casting `1` isn't safe. However, you can use any random valid pointer:

```
void foo() {
   static char dummy; // static keeps the pointer valid
   put_func(nullptr);
   put_func(&dummy); //not the nullptr
}
```

Note that you probably can also do

```
void put_bool(bool b) { put_func(new bool(b)); }
bool get_bool() { bool* p = get_func(); bool b = *p; delete p; return b; }
```

but we have not enough context to know if this leaks memory.